# Change elements z-index by click on another

Tags: jquery, html, css, z-index

in advance thank for any help or advice, and sorry if my english is bad :)

I have a html element like this:

```
<a id="menu-click" onclick="$('#menu-left').slideToggle('fast');return false;"></a>
```

Click on this element open a menu what slide down, that's all fine. But since I have more draggible boxes on a page this menu can slide under them. My intention is, after click on menu-click check highes z-index on the page add +1 to this z-index and assign it to the menu-left. And i need this function work for more similar elements.

I already us jQuery function for the draggible boxes and it work great. But i dont know how to make a function for elements opened after click on another.

Here is the function i use for boxes:

```
$(function() {
    var c = [
    "#box1", 
    "#box2", 
    "#box3", 
    "#box4"
    ];
    var boxes = c.join(", ");
    // Set up mousedown handlers for each box
    $(boxes).mousedown(function() {
        var el = $(this), // The box that was clicked
            max = 0;

    // Find the highest z-index
    $(boxes).each(function() {
        // Find the current z-index value
        var z = parseInt( $( this ).css( "z-index" ), 10 );
        // Keep either the current max, or the current z-index, whichever is higher
        max = Math.max( max, z );
    });

    // Set the box that was clicked to the highest z-index plus one
    el.css("z-index", max + 1 );
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you are saying, you what a function which returns the highest z-index , max +1 assign it to #menu-left  ? Am I Right??

Comment: Yes, but execute this function after click on "#menu-click".        Basically: click on "#menu-click" > open "#menu-left"> change "#menu-left" z-index to max +1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is here.

```
$(function() {
var c = [
"#box1", 
"#box2", 
"#box3", 
"#box4"
];
var boxes = c.join(", ");
// Set up mousedown handlers for each box
$(boxes).mousedown(function() {
    var el = $(this), // The box that was clicked
        max = 0;

// Find the highest z-index
$(boxes).each(function() {
     $( this ).css( "z-index" , 10); //first assign the value and then get it
    // Find the current z-index value
    var z = parseInt( $( this ).css( "z-index" ));//get the zindex after assigning
    // Keep either the current max, or the current z-index, whichever is higher
    max = Math.max( max, z );
});

// Set the box that was clicked to the highest z-index plus one
el.css("z-index", max + 1 );
});
```

});

Comment: This will set all boxs to a zindex of 11 everytime.

Comment: This work fine but, do you think there is a way to assign for each box different z-index and only one box what I click will be with highest one?

Comment: I mean something like this: box1:z-index=10, box2:z-index=20, box3:z-index=30, box4:z-index=40. And when I click on box1 its zindex change for 40 and box4 change for 10. Hope you understand me :D

Comment: Yes I understand you. My motto was to give you a head start. Now you can bend the code as per your requirement. And do please upvote if it really helped you

Comment: I will try some modification. :) And then I post my results if I manage to do what i want. I am beginner with jQuery so it can take little more time. But thx.